# i cannot adjust columns width in a dynamic table layout android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

i have create a table layout as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1"
    android:id="@+id/headertable" >

</TableLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headertable"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1"
        android:id="@+id/maintable" >

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

.java:

```
public class tab_stats extends Fragment {
TextView Position, Player, 
MatchPlayed,Wins,Deuce,Lost,GoalFavor,GoalAgainst,GoalDiference,Points;
TableRow tr,mtr;
TableLayout mt,ht;
String os[]       =  {"Androidddddd","Mango","iOS","Symbian","Bada",
        "Android","Mango","iOS","Symbian","Bada",

"Android","Mango","iOS","Symbian","Bada","Bada","Bada","Bada","Bada","Bada"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_stats, container, false);
    mt = v.findViewById(R.id.maintable);
    ht = v.findViewById(R.id.headertable);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    addHeaders();
    addData();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}

/** getActivity()function add the headers to the table **/
public void addHeaders(){
    /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
    tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    tr.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 2); //Border between rows

    /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
    TextView Position = new TextView(getActivity());
    Position.setText("#");
    Position.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    Position.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    Position.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
    Position.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    Position.setWidth(20);
    tr.addView(Position);  // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /** Creating another textview **/
    TextView Player = new TextView(getActivity());
    Player.setText("Player");
    Player.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    Player.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
    Player.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    Player.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    Player.setWidth(160);
    tr.addView(Player); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /** Creating another textview **/
    TextView MatchPlayed = new TextView(getActivity());
    MatchPlayed.setText("MP");
    MatchPlayed.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    MatchPlayed.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
    MatchPlayed.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    MatchPlayed.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    MatchPlayed.setWidth(60);
    tr.addView(MatchPlayed); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /** Creating another textview **/
    TextView Wins = new TextView(getActivity());
    Wins.setText("W");
    Wins.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    Wins.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
    Wins.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    Wins.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    Wins.setWidth(60);
    tr.addView(Wins); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /** Creating another textview **/
    TextView Deuce = new TextView(getActivity());
    Deuce.setText("D");
    Deuce.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    Deuce.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
    Deuce.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    Deuce.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    Deuce.setWidth(60);
    tr.addView(Deuce); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /** Creating another textview **/
    TextView Lost = new TextView(getActivity());
    Lost.setText("L");
    Lost.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    Lost.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
    Lost.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    Lost.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    Lost.setWidth(60);
    tr.addView(Lost); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /** Creating another textview **/
    TextView GoalFavor = new TextView(getActivity());
    GoalFavor.setText("GF");
    GoalFavor.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    GoalFavor.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
    GoalFavor.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    GoalFavor.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    GoalFavor.setWidth(60);
    tr.addView(GoalFavor); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /** Creating another textview **/
    TextView GoalAgainst = new TextView(getActivity());
    GoalAgainst.setText("GA");
    GoalAgainst.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    GoalAgainst.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
    GoalAgainst.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    GoalAgainst.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    GoalAgainst.setWidth(60);
    tr.addView(GoalAgainst); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /** Creating another textview **/
    TextView GoalDiference = new TextView(getActivity());
    GoalDiference.setText("GD");
    GoalDiference.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    GoalDiference.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
    GoalDiference.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    GoalDiference.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    GoalDiference.setWidth(60);
    tr.addView(GoalDiference); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /** Creating another textview **/
    TextView Points = new TextView(getActivity());
    Points.setText("Pts");
    Points.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    Points.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
    Points.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    Points.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    Points.setWidth(60);
    tr.addView(Points); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    ht.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}

/** getActivity()function add the data to the table **/
public void addData(){
    getdata();

    for (int i = 0; i < os.length; i++)
    {
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        mtr = new TableRow(getActivity());
        mtr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        Position = new TextView(getActivity());
        Position.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d", i+1));
        Position.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        Position.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        Position.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Position.setWidth(20);
        Position.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        Position.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        mtr.addView(Position);  // Adding textView to tablerow.


        /** Creating another textview **/
        Player = new TextView(getActivity());
        Player.setText(os[i]);
        Player.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        Player.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Player.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        Player.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        Player.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        Player.setWidth(160);
        mtr.addView(Player); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating another textview **/
        MatchPlayed = new TextView(getActivity());
        MatchPlayed.setText("199");
        MatchPlayed.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        MatchPlayed.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        MatchPlayed.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        MatchPlayed.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        MatchPlayed.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        MatchPlayed.setWidth(60);
        mtr.addView(MatchPlayed); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating another textview **/
        Wins = new TextView(getActivity());
        Wins.setText("999");
        Wins.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        Wins.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Wins.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        Wins.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        Wins.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        Wins.setWidth(60);
        mtr.addView(Wins); // Adding textView to tablerow.


        /** Creating another textview **/
        Deuce = new TextView(getActivity());
        Deuce.setText("100");
        Deuce.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        Deuce.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Deuce.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        Deuce.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        Deuce.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        Deuce.setWidth(60);
        mtr.addView(Deuce); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating another textview **/
        Lost = new TextView(getActivity());
        Lost.setText("555");
        Lost.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        Lost.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Lost.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        Lost.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        Lost.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        Lost.setWidth(60);
        mtr.addView(Lost); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating another textview **/
        GoalFavor = new TextView(getActivity());
        GoalFavor.setText("444");
        GoalFavor.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        GoalFavor.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        GoalFavor.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        GoalFavor.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        GoalFavor.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        GoalFavor.setWidth(60);
        mtr.addView(GoalFavor); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating another textview **/
        GoalAgainst = new TextView(getActivity());
        GoalAgainst.setText("1");
        GoalAgainst.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        GoalAgainst.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        GoalAgainst.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        GoalAgainst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        GoalAgainst.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        GoalAgainst.setWidth(60);
        mtr.addView(GoalAgainst); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating another textview **/
        GoalDiference = new TextView(getActivity());
        GoalDiference.setText("99");
        GoalDiference.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        GoalDiference.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        GoalDiference.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        GoalDiference.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        GoalDiference.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        GoalDiference.setWidth(60);
        mtr.addView(GoalDiference); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating another textview **/
        Points = new TextView(getActivity());
        Points.setText("742");
        Points.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        Points.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Points.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        Points.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        Points.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        Points.setWidth(60);
        mtr.addView(Points); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        mt.addView(mtr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}

public void getdata(){

}
}
```

i am creating the rows dynamically so it is depending on the amount of friends the person have.

the problem is that when running the program in different cell phones, the table could look fine as it could look distorted. how can i make the first column be fixed and the other one to get arrange depending on the size of the info inside?

this is how it looks:

[image]

i want the first column to be fixed to 3 digits and the other columns to just adjust

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you are referring to the # column? You are creating it with these settings:

```
Position.setWidth(20);

.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
```

You can remove those and add these:

```
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            //Puts the text to the right of the textview
            android:gravity="right"

            //Puts the text view to the far left of screen
            android:layout_gravity="left"

            //Ensures all # column text views are the same width. 
            android:minWidth="45dp"
```

You should try to avoid hard-coded widths and heights in your layouts. For your first column, it shouldn't be an issue, but it doesn't offer much flexibility when you set all your widths to specific dp values.

Comment: I did this in my xml. I knew you were doing it dynamically and still posted this. You will have to find the method call for each one to set them to the textview dynamically. You should look into a ListView and array adapter to achieve these results with a lot less code.